# How can I extend Bootstrap classes in SASS if I only liked to bootstrap in the HTML file?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am wondering how I can extend bootstrap classes in SASS if I have linked to the bootstrap stylesheet in my HTML file, like done below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <title>Some title</title>
    </head>
```

I then have a .scss file that generates the additional css file I have also linked to in the head of my HTML document. But for example, If I try to extend any Bootstrap class from the .scss file, like I did here:

```
    .p3 {
    @extend .p-3;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
```

it throws an error saying:

Sass::SyntaxError: ".p3" failed to @extend ".p-3".
The selector ".p-3" was not found.
Use "@extend .p-3 !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.

how do I solve this?

Many thanks,

Comment: that is not possible. if you do have a scss file then why not import bootstrap to it?

Comment: SASS requires a compiler on the server side. You can't run/parse SASS in the browser

Comment: Are you using a CLI of some sort? It's pretty easy to include the node_module for bootstrap in your project and append their `.scss` files [into your build pipeline](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/theming/) with a settings configuration to build it out however you please with only the parts you want. Otherwise you'll just have to use a bunch of selector overrides to override the original bootstrap classes.

Comment: karthick how do I import bootstrap to a css file?
Chris W. I have no idea what a CLI is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include bootstrap by importing it in your main.scss.

something like:

```
@import 'bootstrap.scss';

.yourClass {
   @extend .p-3;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

For more info read the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/)